# Theme broken shopping cart layout

Tags: magento2, css, frontend

I bought a theme that has an issue with the shopping cart preview layout.
Here is an example: http://bannerbag.de/test2layer.html

Add a product to the shopping cart and hover the mouse over the cart.

[image]

If you click on the cart it does however display products correctly.

I am new to magento and I dont know how to fix this .. the seller also didn't respond to emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix this by setting the height of the class

```
minicart-items-wrapper
```

in CSS to another value, for example:

```
.minicart-items-wrapper {
    height: 220px
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set number of minicart product item from admin:

Admin -> Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart Sidebar>Number of Items to Display Scrollbar

[image]